# Inductive proof on r

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $r, n ∈ N$ and let $r ≤ n$. Give an inductive proof for:

$$ {n+1 \choose r + 1} =  ∑_{k=r}^n {k \choose r} $$

Step 1: We will prove this using induction on n.
n = 1

Step 2: n = k, prove for n = 1.

Am I on the right track? Not sure where to go from there though

Comment: No, in Step 2 you have to assume that your expession for $n$ is correct. In Step 3 you have to show it for $n+1$. In the last step you have to use your result from Step 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity you are trying to prove is known as the "Hockey Stick Identity".
The base case should be n = r and not n = 1.

Base Case: n = r
$$\sum^{n}_{k=r}\binom{k}{r}= \sum^{r}_{k=r}\binom{k}{r}= \binom{r}{r}=1=\binom{r+1}{r+1}$$

Inductive Hypothesis:
Assume $$\sum^{n}_{k=r}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$ is true for some $n \ge r$.

Inductive Step: n + 1
$$\sum^{n+1}_{k=r}\binom{k}{r}= \sum^{n}_{k=r}\binom{k}{r} + \binom{n+1}{r} $$
$$=\binom{n+1}{r+1} + \binom{n+1}{r}\quad\quad$$
$$=\binom{n+2}{r+1}$$